# Mocking out a function inside another function

Tags: jasmine

I don't actually want 'anotherFunction' to execute.
But rather when it's called inside someFunction, to have it return a specific value rather than actually executing:

```
// Testing this function
export function someFunction(foo, bar): string {
  // want to provide a mock result here
  const baz = anotherFunction(foo, bar);

  // do something unrelated
}

export function anotherFunction(quz, quux): any {
  // do something unrelated
}
```

How would you go about this with [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/)? The examples I find all assume a class and then use:

```
// Can't use this as the method I'd like to "mock out" is not in a class
const spy = spyOn(someClass, 'aMethod');
```

I'm looking for something similar to the mock function in Jest. [That documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) helps communicate my question better:

> *"Mock functions allow you to test the links between code by erasing the actual implementation of a function, ..."*

But then something similar in Jasmine.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a test double in that context, `anotherFunction` is effectively a private method.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import * as helpers from './file/where/anotherFunction/is';
...
spyOn(helpers, 'anotherFunction');
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414#issuecomment-393817117) out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting the same error as described in that article: `is not declared writable or has no setter`. Seems that testing a single function isn't possible with Jasmine. :\

Comment: I remember doing it like so a long time ago in Angular 5. Maybe Jasmine has changed ever since then.